# Immediate Functions have returns of different types using es6

Tags: ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

```
const contains1 = (() => {
  debugger;
  Array.prototype.includes
    ? (arr, value) => arr.includes(value)
    : (arr, value) => arr.some(el => el === value)
})()
```

When I call contains1,it returns undefined.

```
const contains2 = (() => 
   Array.prototype.includes
    ? (arr, value) => arr.includes(value)
    : (arr, value) => arr.some(el => el === value)
)()
```

But When I call contains2,it returns a function.

Why it happens to have different returns?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebZOc.png)

Comment: Because the first one doesn't have any return?

Comment: But the second one has no return,either. I have upload my test pic.@Bergi

Comment: The second one uses a concise body (no braces) with an implicit return. Please read the answer on the duplicate.